# Inheritance, commands and event sourcing

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

In order not to redo things several times I wanted to factorize common stuff. For Instance, let's say we have a cow and a horse.  The cow produces milk, the horse runs fast, but both eat grass.

```
public class Herbivorous
{
   protected int Quantity;

   public void EatGrass(int quantity)
   {
      var evt= Build.GrassEaten
                    .WithQuantity(quantity);
      RaiseEvent(evt);
   }

   public void Apply(GrassEaten evt)
   {
       _quantity= evt.Quantity;
   }
}

public class Horse : Herbivorous
{
   private bool _HasFastRun;

   public void RunFast()
   {
      var evt= Build.FastRun;
      RaiseEvent(evt);
   }

   public void Apply(FastRunevt)
   {
       _HasFastRun= true;
   }
}

public class Cow: Herbivorous
{
   private bool _IsMilkProduced;

   public void ProduceMilk()
   {
      var evt= Build.MilkProduced;
      RaiseEvent(evt);
   }

   public void Apply(MilkProduced evt)
   {
       _IsMilkProduced= true;
   }
}
```

To eat Grass, my application receives a command in Json or xml, or whatever that deserialise into this class:

```
namespace Herbivorous
{
   public class EatGrass : CommandBase
   {
      public Guid IdHerbivorous {get; set;}
      public Guid CommitId {get; set;}
      public long Version {get; set;}
      public int Quantity {get; set;}
   }
}
```

The command handler should be :

```
public class EatGrassHandler : CommandHandler<EatGrass>
{
   public override CommandValidation Execute(EatGrass cmd)
   {
      Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(cmd != null);
      Herbivorous herbivorous= EventRepository.GetById<Herbivorous>(cmd.Id);
      if (herbivorous.IsNull())
         throw new AggregateRootInstanceNotFoundException();
      herbivorous.EatGrass(cmd.Quantity);
      EventRepository.Save(herbivorous, cmd.CommitId);
   }
}
```

so far so good. I get a Herbivorous object , I have access to its EatGrass function, whether it is a horse or a cow doesn't matter really. The only problem is here :

```
EventRepository.GetById<Herbivorous>(cmd.Id)
```

Indeed, let's imagine we have a cow that has produced milk during the morning and now wants to eat grass.  The EventRepository contains an event MilkProduced, and then come the command EatGrass.
With the CommandHandler, we are no longer in the presence of a cow and the herbivorious doesn't know anything about producing milk . what should it do?

Should I have explicit contextual command  like :

```
namespace Herbivorous.Cow
    {
       public class EatGrass : CommandBase
       {
          public Guid IdHerbivorous {get; set;}
          public Guid CommitId {get; set;}
          public long Version {get; set;}
          public int Quantity {get; set;}
       }
       public class ProduceMilk : CommandBase
       {
          public Guid IdHerbivorous {get; set;}
          public Guid CommitId {get; set;}
          public long Version {get; set;}
       }
    }
```

This would mean that the external component that asks my herbivorous to eat grass should know that in this bounded context we talk about a cow. in the former command, we were talking about a general Herbivorous behavior, so the context of my call was not important. We knew that we needed herbivorous to eat grass that was all.

This is my main problem possible leakage of domain specific from one bounded context to another. 
Actually It might mean too that I cannot support abstraction when working on interfaces between several applications. I wonder...

Or I could just accept any event when rebuilding my herbivorous. It means that if it does not find a method to apply this event to, he will goes just fine trying to apply the next one of its stream. This is the real simple solution, but it does not put me at ease to know  that events might not be applied ( and not producing errors) when rehydrating my object. (Actually the more I think about it the less I feel guilty..)

Thanks for your help, I am just beginning with these kinds of problem, and I would be glad to have some news from someone more experienced.

Comment: Sure you want a different command handler for each possible command, like in your example above? If yes, where is the problem, you could easily change it to create an instance of the related subclass.

Comment: Exactly, surely my mind was twisting on its own... Maybe I needed to explain  it to someone so that I could go trough it. thanks for your help. I am going to delete this question, because it makes no sense actually... Sorry, for needing psychological help :D. Anyday you need someone to read you, I'll be there! :p

Comment: Well, my suggestion below was aiming at building a *generic* command handler, doing the object creation in a generic fashion and letting the individual subclasses themselves doing the `Execute` part of the command. That's how I would try to build such a system.

Comment: Interesting. I am trying to have a command handler  foreach different command.  Quite new to all of this, so my words might not fit in perfectly, but the command handler is kind of Application service. Well thanks anyway, I have understood your point, and if need is I would have ideas about how to build such a generic handler. have a nice day.

Comment: Possibly related: the principle of leaky abstractions. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction and http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html

Comment: @acculus : could you be please more specific and develop an answer, please?

Answer (score 1):

First, add a virtual method `Execute(cmd)` to your `Herbivorous`, and put the code for the dispatching the commands to the command methods there. Then each subclass of `Herbivorous` can override that method and support all command methods specific to the subclass. Should look somehow like this:

```
public class Cow: Herbivorous
{
   public override void Execute(Command cmd)
   {
      if(cmd is ProduceMilkCommand)
          ProduceMilk(cmd);  // execute specific command
      else
          base.Execute(cmd); // delegate general commands to the base class
   }
}
```

For creating a new object from a given command, add a `System.Type` field to your `cmd` and use reflection to create an instance of that specific subtype of `Herbivorous`. Or use the [prototype pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) to create a new instance (your command has to store a reference to that prototype object then instead). A third alternative is to use the [abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), your command then will have to store a reference to the right factory subtype.

Of course, I guess I could give you a better answer if you had shown us how the command class currently looks like and how the commands are created. And your use of the "var" command in the code snippets hides some details which may be important for a more precise answer.

Comment: Ick.  `Execute(cmd)` ...Really?  I would have thought providing a more general interface like `Mammalius` would have been a better solution for the repository.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: in my understanding, the OP wants the problem to be solved that different subclasses are responsible for different commands. To introduce a more general interface does not solve that problem, it just bypasses it. Perhaps that is what the OP wants (I guess not, but I may be wrong).

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your answer. I have updated my question to be more precise. I'll have a look at what you tell me to understand how it might fit into my present problem.

Comment: I have changed several little things so takes the time to really read it carefully my changes were a bit everywhere.. ;)

Comment: Always nice to ask question because it forces you to explain everything and makes your mind much more clearer.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's okay for your Herbivorous class to skip events it doesn't understand.

I learned a lot about this and related issues in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/dddcqrs/ufWJEnXjo-s/sLQ_5frFsUIJ).

Hope that helps. I wish there were cows and horses in my domain!!